# php get file content of downloadable file

Tags: php, csv

Coult not find any similar problem solved on the web, so here's my situation:

I have a .jsp "webpage" that generates a .csv file based on specific parameters.
As an example, if I use my browser to open the site, I type in:

```
redownloadsubmitter.jsp?id=225&batch_id=2013_11_20&orgshort=NEP
```

The script then uses the data in the query string and generates the matching .csv file, named: `NEP_DETAILS_2013_11_20.csv`

Now what I want is to not manually having to use my browser, open the script and download the file to my local harddrive. Instead I want to use a PHP script that grabs the content and then can further format it, based on my needs.

I thought about the following code, but that did not work. Instead it returns nothing, empty website when I try it..

```
$download = file_get_contents('redownloadsubmitter.jsp?id=225&batch_id=2013_11_20&orgshort=NEP');
echo $download;
```

Any other ideas?

**NOTE**: just in case someone has this question: I have no access to the .jsp file and I therefore cannot change how it operates.

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents()` isn't smart and doesn't know that's a URL you're passing in. It's trying to literally open a local file whose name is `redownloadsubmitted.jsp.etc.....`.

If you want f_g_c() to do an HTTP operation, then you'll have to include a full-blown URL:

```
$download = file_get_contents('http://example.com/redownloadsubmitter.jsp etc....');'
```

Comment: Hi Marc, I did include the full URL in my code but that was the solution that did not work. How do I get this to work instead? I believe the file content of the script is empty, so of course f_g_c() won't work. How can I get the file contents of the .csv that I am prompted to download?

Comment: if it's empty, and the url you're using in both places is identical, thenc heck into why it's empty - do you have to log in to the real site? Then you'll need to replicate that login in PHP.

Comment: I checked it and I am logged in, that is fine. With the code from Zjmainstay, I am able to use my php script to access the .jsp file. However, it then prompts me to download. I don't want that. I need the content of this .csv returned so I can work with it.

Comment: then don't echo it. `$download` would have the contents of the file, so just start working with it.

Comment: this is exactly my problem: the $download variable is empty.  The purpose of echo above is simply to check if something is there, and there isn't anything while there should be something. If I manually open the link I get prompted the download (as already mentioned) and then I have data in the downloaded file. But with the f_g_c I have nothing.

Comment: yes, and? Like I said, if you have to log in through your browser to get that file, you'll have to replicate the login in PHP. e.g. if your browser has a cookie, then PHP has no way to access that cookie, because it's running on the server, NOT your local machine

Comment: yes, you're right. I checked more into it and I found out that there is another script (portalLoginSubmitter.jsp) that authenticates the user. I have of course login information, but I don't know how to replicate a logon from the php script. What would be the answer here I tried to search on the net, because I have myself not much experience with this area of PHP or JSP, but can't seem to find the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for download file.

```
<?php
/**
 *  $filename       filename in server
 *  $downloadname   filename when download file
 */
$filename = __FILE__;
$dowloadname = 'PHPDownload.php';
Header("content-type:application/octet-stream"); 
Header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
Header("Accept-Length: ".filesize($filename));
Header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$dowloadname);
if(file_exists($filename) && $fp=fopen($filename,"r"))  //file exists and open it 
{ 
    echo fread($fp,filesize($filename));    //read write to the browser 
    fclose($fp); 
}

//End_php
```

Comment: Okay, this code seems to go in the right direction. Basically it finds the .csv file, but it prompts me to download instead of printing it into the browser or making it available so that I can edit it. Any suggestions?